# FluentNHibernate automap to backing field

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

In our project we use MVC3 with a domain model and NHibernate as DAL.
We configure NHibernate with fluent configuration using auto mapping.
At the moment we are trying to devise a validation strategy. 
We need validations that go beyond data annotations. 
One place where we are sure to catch all attempts to alter (and corrupt) the data would be the property setters. As some checks involve querying the database, we do not want to do that when NHibernate restored objects form the database.
So for this to be a viable solution: Can we instruct FluentNhibernate to satandard AutoMap to the backing fields of the properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [explicitly tell FNH to use a backing field](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Mapping_a_collection_that_uses_a_private_backing_field): unfortunately AutoMapping support looks unlikely out-of-the box as there doesn't seem to be anything applicable in the [configuration options](http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Automapping/IAutomappingConfiguration.htm).

Comment: The auto mapping is a key issue, adding mappings for all classes & properties, would be way to time consuming.

Comment: I have continued looking, but I cannot find any "generic" setting either. I guess it cannot be done >:-(